# Hide RoutingErrors from production.log for images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

How to hide from *production.log* all routing errors to users uploaded files like this

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/*

Answer (score 1):

An easy way will be to use the Silencer gem: https://github.com/stve/silencer

Something like this should work:

```
config.middleware.swap Rails::Rack::Logger, Silencer::Logger, :silence => [%r{^/uploads/}]
```

Comment: Did you add that line into config/production.rb?

You can also try 
    `config.middleware.swap Rails::Rack::Logger, Silencer::Logger, :silence => ['ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/*']`
And remember to reboot the app.

Comment: Silencer is only threadsafe in Rails version 4.2.6 and later. Thai is why it's now working for me.

Comment: Have upgraded to Rails 4.2.6. Still not working. https://github.com/stve/silencer/issues/18